# ReactJS and Material UI TreeView: can I use a JSON/array of object to populate the TreeView?

Tags: json, reactjs, treeview, material-ui

I have an array of object containing the values that need to populate the `<TreeView>` component:

```
const treeItems = [
    {
        id: uuidv4(),
        name: 'English',
        children: [
            {
                id: uuidv4(),
                name: 'Spring',
                children: []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: uuidv4(),
        name: 'Italian',
        children: [
            {
                id: uuidv4(),
                name: 'Level A',
                children: []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to use it as a prop to automatically populate the `TreeView` with `TreeItems`.

Currently I have a function that renders the children when you pass the array, but checking the documentation (https://material-ui.com/api/tree-view/) I noticed that there is a prop for children.

> children  node        The content of the component.

Is it possible to use JSON/array of object to populate the TreeView?

Comment: That `children` is the child components that you wrap inside. For using content of your array you would have to map on it

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. Actually I found that RSUITE 3 has a Tree component that allows to pass a JSON to populate it (https://rsuitejs.com/en/components/tree) which is exactly what I need.

Comment: I guess then you can either opt to use another library and bloat your app or just use coding to keep using material ui which may already have at other places in your app. I guess its your development environment setting/choice on which was you want to go forward with.

Comment: I would not mix both libraries. Since I'm at an early stage of development switching would be done pretty quickly.

Answer (score 22):

The `TreeView` component doesn't have anything built-in for this, but it is fairly straightforward to create re-usable code to provide this functionality for a given data structure.

Here is one way to do it:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import TreeView from "@material-ui/lab/TreeView";
import TreeItem from "@material-ui/lab/TreeItem";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import { sampleFromStackOverflowQuestion, seasons } from "./sampleData";

const getTreeItemsFromData = treeItems => {
  return treeItems.map(treeItemData => {
    let children = undefined;
    if (treeItemData.children && treeItemData.children.length > 0) {
      children = getTreeItemsFromData(treeItemData.children);
    }
    return (
      <TreeItem
        key={treeItemData.id}
        nodeId={treeItemData.id}
        label={treeItemData.name}
        children={children}
      />
    );
  });
};
const DataTreeView = ({ treeItems }) => {
  return (
    <TreeView
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
    >
      {getTreeItemsFromData(treeItems)}
    </TreeView>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DataTreeView treeItems={sampleFromStackOverflowQuestion} />
      <br />
      <DataTreeView treeItems={seasons} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Data-driven TreeView]

`DataTreeView` and `getTreeItemsFromData` could be moved into a separate file and then imported in order to reuse them in multiple components.

Here is a Typescript version:

```
import * as React from "react";

import TreeView from "@material-ui/lab/TreeView";
import TreeItem from "@material-ui/lab/TreeItem";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import {
  sampleFromStackOverflowQuestion,
  seasons,
  TreeItemData
} from "./sampleData";

const getTreeItemsFromData = (treeItems: TreeItemData[]) => {
  return treeItems.map(treeItemData => {
    let children = undefined;
    if (treeItemData.children && treeItemData.children.length > 0) {
      children = getTreeItemsFromData(treeItemData.children);
    }
    return (
      <TreeItem
        key={treeItemData.id}
        nodeId={treeItemData.id}
        label={treeItemData.name}
        children={children}
      />
    );
  });
};
interface DataTreeViewProps {
  treeItems: TreeItemData[];
}
function DataTreeView({ treeItems }: DataTreeViewProps) {
  return (
    <TreeView
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
    >
      {getTreeItemsFromData(treeItems)}
    </TreeView>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DataTreeView treeItems={sampleFromStackOverflowQuestion} />
      <br />
      <DataTreeView treeItems={seasons} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Typescript data-driven TreeView]

Comment: I didn't know `TreeView` doesn't accept `items`. But i guess it try to put all display layer as a `children`. If this is the case, then this answer seems very solid to me.

Comment: how we can convert this with typescript?.. 
It giving me error "Binding element 'treeItems' implicitly has an 'any' type"
near const DataTreeView = ({ treeItems })

Comment: @DhawalMhatre Sorry, but I don't personally use Typescript, so I can't help much with advice on how to add appropriate types into this.

Comment: @DhawalMhatre I started learning some Typescript today, so I added a Typescript version.

Comment: this will only work if nested elements have same properties

Comment: @Ryan Cogswell How would you add a label icon to this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way to day as mentioned in the Material UI Docs.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TreeView from '@material-ui/lab/TreeView';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import TreeItem from '@material-ui/lab/TreeItem';
import _ from 'lodash';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    height: 216,
    flexGrow: 1,
    maxWidth: 400,
  },
});

export default function ControlledTreeView(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = React.useState('');
  const [stateData, setStateData] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      const { data } = props;
      setStateData(data);
    },
    [props],
  );

  const handleToggle = (event, nodeIds) => {
    setExpanded(nodeIds);
  };

  const handleSelect = (event, nodeIds) => {
    setSelected(nodeIds);
  };

  const onSearch = (search) => {
    setSearchValue(search);
    console.log(searchTree(search, props.data));
  };

  function searchTree(str, data) {
    const searchStr = str.toLowerCase();

    // Only return the entries that contain a matched value
    return _.filter(data, (datum) => {
      // Check if name matches
      return _.includes(datum.name, searchStr)
      || _.some(datum.activities, (activity) => {
          return _.entries(activity.routines).some(([routine, {details}]) => {
            // Check if dynamic routine matches or details
            return _.includes(routine, searchStr) || _.includes(details, searchStr);
          });
        });
    });
  };

  const renderTree = (nodes) => (
    <TreeItem key={nodes.id} nodeId={nodes.id} label={nodes.name}>
      {Array.isArray(nodes.children) ? nodes.children.map((node) => renderTree(node)) : null}
    </TreeItem>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <TreeView
        className={classes.root}
        defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        defaultExpanded={['root']}
        defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
      >
        {renderTree(stateData)}
      </TreeView>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And you can call this component as
`<CustomizedTreeView data={TreeViewData} />`

where your `TreeViewData` will be

```
const TreeViewData = {
  id: 'root',
  name: 'Documents',
  children: [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Report',
      children: [
        {
          id: '2',
          name: 'PDF',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'Files',
      children: [
        {
          id: '4',
          name: 'Excel',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '5',
      name: 'Programs',
      children: [
        {
          id: '6',
          name: 'Codes',
        },
        {
          id: '7',
          name: 'Data',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```